# Relation and proving reflexivity

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

The relation *R* is defined on integers by $xRy$ if and only if $x^2y=ymod6$.
Prove that $R$ is reflexive.

So far I have:

Let $x=y$

$x^2x=xmod6$

I don't know how to go from here... because $x^2=0mod6$ is not true...

Comment: There aren't many cases. If you have no better idea, check all remainders modulo $6$ individually.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We have

$$x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$$
so for three consecutive numbers certainly there is one multiple of $2$ and another multiple of $3$.